# Java Swing NullPointerException when drawing

Tags: java, swing, drawing, nullpointerexception, jlayeredpane

I'm using a custom JLayeredPane.
I have several Shapes which needed to be drawn on different layers in the JLayeredPane.

To test this I create a JPanel and ask its graphics. Then I draw a test rectangle on that JPanel (preparing the graphics) and in my paintComponent method from the JLayeredPane I finally draw everything. But this fails (NullPointerException).

```
public class MyCustomPanel extends JLayeredPane {

// test
JPanel testpane;
Graphics g2;
// test

// constructor
public MyCustomPanel() {
    testpane = new JPanel();
    this.add(testpane, new Integer(14));
    g2 = testpane.getGraphics();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g2.drawRect(10, 10, 300, 300);
}
```

}

```
// run:
//Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
//        at view.MyCustomPanel.paintComponent(MyCustomPanel.java:65)
```

Why can't I draw on such a JPanel from within my JLayeredPane? I can draw directly on my JLayeredPane from within my paintComponent method but that's on the default Panel from the JLayeredPane. I need to create and draw on several layers which are added in my JLayeredPane.

What am I doing wrong? :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `g2` casting the `Graphics` that is passed to you:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

Why don't you try decoupling things?

```
class InnerPanel extends JPanel
{
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
     g2.drawRect(....);
  }
}

class MyLayered extends JLayeredPane()
{
  MyLayered()
  {
    this.add(new InnerPanel(), 14);
  }
}
```

this makes more sense..

Also because you are trying to do something that doesn't agree with Swing behaviour.
Swing will care by itself to call the appropriate `paint` methods over things that must be displayed, and to go with this protocol you should tell `Graphics` objects what to draw when Swing asks it to your objects (calling the `paint`) method, not when you want to do it.

In this way whenever Swing wants to draw your `JLayeredPane` you just draw things on a `Graphic` object of other things without considering that Swing will call their appropriate methods when it's the right time to do so.

In conclusion: **you can't draw something on a `Graphic` object when you want it. You can do it just inside methods invoked by Swing, because otherwise `Graphics` of these objects doesn't mean anything**

Comment: But this will use the graphics from the JLayredPane and not from my JPanel. So I would draw on my JLayredPane and not on my JPanel ? :s

Comment: @Why don't you try decoupling things?

I don't want to decouple this. How can I draw from within my JLayredPane on a JPanel without creating a custom JPanel? :s

Comment: Then you should think twice about object oriented programming, why should you want to implement custom drawing of objects outside themselves? This makes no sense.. What will you do with 5 different panels? Store all their graphics objects and draw on them on paintComponent of the layered pane?

Comment: I was going to suggest doing the rectangle drawing in the inner panel as well, but you beat me too it.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

The variable g2 is probably null because you set it in the constructor, not when drawing.  Instead, use the "g" that was passed in.

You can only get a legitimate Graphics from a component that is currently being painted. Otherwise, it's not valid. At the point you're requesting it, the MyCustomPanel() isn't being displayed, and neither is testpane.

Comment: But the g is from the JLayeredPane and not from the JPanel. I need to draw that rectangle on my JFrame so I need the graphics from that JFrame and not the g (graphics) from my JLayeredPane :s

Comment: @jufo, You can only get a legitimate Graphics from a component that is currently being painted.  Otherwise, it's not valid.  At the point you're requesting it, the MyCustomPanel() isn't being displayed, and neither is testpane.